# Why does this miller rabin test implement the use of n-1 instead of -1?

Tags: python, algorithm

Well, i was learning Miller-Rabin Primality test algorithm through this tutorial([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BWTS_1Nxao)). At 8:28, instead of checking `if pow(a,exp,n)==-1`in the last while loop, he used `if pow(a,exp,n)==n-1`. Why does it have to be n-1? I did check it by writing it in C++ and turns out, n-1 is the only possible way of getting the right answer(he did also try to explain why but it is just weird to me). Why is this the case? It makes no sense to me, It is supposed to be -1 instead of n-1 and n-1 makes it work but -1 doesn't make it work. I really need someone to clarify this for me. One more thing, i did watch the first video where he explains how the algorithm works so i think i comprehended most of what he said.

Comment: thats not a question about c++ code. The video uses python

Comment: Withouth knowing the implementation of pow(a,exp,n) I could not say for sure. But modulo n it should work out (maybe pow(a,exp,n) adds an extra n to avoid negative numbers)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Can you pls explain it further what you mean?

Comment: `a == b (mod n)` if and only if `a - b % n == 0` in your case `(-1 - (n - 1)) % n == -n % n == 0`, so `-1 == n - 1 (mod n)` and you can interchange them

Comment: @molbdnilo has the detailed explanation that should be considered an answer

Answer (score 2):

It's not supposed to be `-1` - the condition is that the power is *congruent* to -1 in modulo n arithmetic. (`A` is congruent to `B` modulo `N` if and only if `A mod N = B mod N`.)

`pow(a,exp,n)` never produces a negative result - `a` is positive - and in modulo `n` arithmetic, `n - 1 = -1 mod n`.
Also, the behaviour of the `%` operator with negative operands in C++ used to be implementation-defined, so `-1 % n` is not really an option.

So `n-1` is mathematically equivalent *and* portable.